# sencha calendar error uncaught type error : Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

i am using sencha calendar for booking-sheduled when i load page it will give me an error uncaught type error : Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined if i clicked on console trace than it will redirect to ext-4.1.0.all

### console error

```
        Ext.String.urlAppendext-4.1.0.all.js:21 Ext.apply.urlAppendext-4.1.0.all.js:21 Ext.define.buildUrlext-4.1.0.all.js:21 Ext.define.buildRequestext-4.1.0.all.js:21 Ext.define.doRequestext-4.1.0.all.js:21 Ext.define.readext-4.1.0.all.js:21 Ext.define.loadext-4.1.0.all.js:21 b.implement.callParentext-4.1.0.all.js:21 Ext.define.loadgrouping.js:373 App.Scheduler.createGridgrouping.js:50 App.Scheduler.initgrouping.js:42 (anonymous function)ext-4.1.0.all.js:21 Ext.util.Event.Ext.extend.isEventext-4.1.0.all.js:21 Ext.util.Event.Ext.extend.fireext-4.1.0.all.js:21 Ext.apply.readyEvent.e.fireext-4.1.0.all.js:21 Ext.apply.fireReadyEventext-4.1.0.all.js:21 (anonymous function)
```

### my grouping.js code

```
        Ext.ns('App');

        Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled : true, disableCaching : true });
        //Ext.Loader.setPath('Sch', '../../js/Sch');



        Ext.require([
            'Sch.panel.SchedulerGrid',
            'Ext.data.*', 
            'Ext.grid.*'    
        ]);

        Ext.onReady(function() {
            Ext.QuickTips.init();

            Sch.preset.Manager.registerPreset('Scheduler', {
        //        timeColumnWidth : 90,
                displayDateFormat : 'M Y',
                shiftIncrement : 2, //increment date for next and previous
                shiftUnit : "DAY",

                timeResolution : {
                    unit : "DAY",
                    increment : 1
                },
                headerConfig : {
                    middle : {
                        unit : "DAY",
                        dateFormat : 'D d M' 
                    },
                    top : {
                        unit : "MONTH",
                        dateFormat : 'M Y'
                    }
                }
            });




            App.Scheduler.init();
        });

        App.Scheduler = {

            // Initialize application
            init : function() {

                this.grid = this.createGrid();
                this.grid.on('eventcontextmenu', this.onEventContextMenu, this);
                //this.grid.on('beforeeventadd', this.onBeforeEventAdd, this);
                var programTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate(
                        '<span class="startTime">{[Ext.Date.format(values.StartDate, "g:i")]}</span>' + 
                        '<span class="programName">{text}</span>' +
                        '<span class="duration">{[values.duration < 3600 ? ((values.duration / 60) + "min") : ((Math.round(10*values.duration/3600)/10) + "h")]}</span>'
                    );
            },


            //for delete the Booking
            onEventContextMenu: function (s, rec, e) {
                e.stopEvent();

                if (!s.ctx) {
                    s.ctx = new Ext.menu.Menu({
                        items: [{
                            text: 'Cancel Booking',
                            iconCls: 'icon-delete',
                            handler : function() {
                                if(s.ctx.rec.getEndDate() < new Date() || s.ctx.rec.getStartDate() < new Date())
                                    {
                                        alert ('You Cant Cancel The Old Booking Record');
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        var r=confirm("Would you like to Cancel Room Booking . \n Room No:" + s.ctx.rec.getResourceId() + "  Booking Date = " +Ext.Date.format(s.ctx.rec.getStartDate(), 'm/d/Y') + '  To  ' + Ext.Date.format(s.ctx.rec.getEndDate(), 'm/d/Y'));
                                        if (r==true)
                                            {
        //                                  activeInactiveBooking();
        //                                  dwrMainCommand.activeInactiveBooking(s.ctx.rec.data.Id,'1',{ async:false,
        //                                          callback : function(data) {
        //                                      alert(data);
                                                s.eventStore.remove(s.ctx.rec);
        //                                  }}
        //                                  );

                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                }
                s.ctx.rec = rec;
                s.ctx.showAt(e.getXY());
            },
            //end delete Booking


            //for the drop event
           /* allowModify : function(s, r) {
                // Don't allow modifications while "fake loading" is happening

                return false;
            },*/
            //end for the drop event
           createGrid : function() {

                Ext.define('Resource', {
                    extend : 'Sch.model.Resource',
                    fields: [
                        'Category',
                        'Type'
                     ]
                });

                var roomList = getRoomAndRoomType();
                var resourceStore = Ext.create('Sch.data.ResourceStore', {
                        groupField : 'Category',
                        sorters: ['Category','Name'],
                        model : 'Resource',
                        data : roomList,

                 });

                 var bookRoom = getBookRoom();
                 var eventStore = Ext.create('Sch.data.EventStore', {
                     url :'http://localhost:8080/DNARMS_NEW/main.htm?hotelId=6',
                     data : bookRoom,
                    });

                //var myDate = new Date();
                var nextDate = new Date();
                nextDate.setDate(new Date().getDate()+6);

                var g = Ext.create("Sch.panel.SchedulerGrid", {
                    height : 635,
        //            width : 815,
                    renderTo : 'grid-grouping'+$('#hiddenHotelId').val(),
                    //renderTo : 'grid-grouping',
                    multiSelect : false,
                    title : 'Booking - Schedule',
                    startDate : new Date(), 
                    endDate : nextDate, 
                    rowHeight : 30,
                    readOnly: false,
                    viewPreset  : 'Scheduler',
                    allowOverlap : false,
                    border : true,
                    dragConfig: null,
                    dropConfig: null,       
                    tooltipTpl : new Ext.XTemplate('{Name} : {[Ext.Date.format(values.StartDate, "m/d/Y")]} - {[Ext.Date.format(values.EndDate, "m/d/Y")]}').compile(),


                    // Constrain events within their current day
                    getDateConstraints: function (resourceRecord, eventRecord) {
                        if (eventRecord) {
                            var date = eventRecord instanceof Date ? eventRecord : eventRecord.getStartDate();
                                //tick = ta.getAt(Math.floor(ta.getTickFromDate(date)));

                            return {
                                start : eventRecord.getStartDate(),
                                end : eventRecord.getEndDate()
                            };
                        }
                    },

                    /*eventRenderer : function(ev, res, tplData) {
                        alert(ev);
                        return ev.getName(); 
                    },*/
                    eventRenderer : function (item, r, tplData, row) {
                        var bgColor = '';

                        if(item.get('Name').search("Un-Availabe") >= 0)
                            {
                                bgColor='red';
                            }
                        else
                            if(item.get('Name').search("Reserved") >= 0)
                            {
                                bgColor='silver';
                            }
                        else
                            if(item.get('Name').search("Check-In") >= 0)
                            {
                                bgColor='gray';
                            }
                        tplData.style = "background-color:" + bgColor +";"+"color:" + " black";

                        return item.get('Name');
                    },

                    headerConfig : {
                        middle : {
                            unit : "DAY",
                            dateFormat : 'D d M' 
                        },
                        top : {
                            unit : "MONTH",
                            dateFormat : 'M Y'
                        }
                    },

                    timeResolution : {
                        unit : "DAY",
                        increment : 1
                    },

                   features : [
                        {
                            ftype : 'grouping',
                            groupHeaderTpl : '{name}',
                            hideGroupedHeader : true
                        }
                    ],

                    // Setup your static columns
                    columns : [
                       {header : 'Projects', width:100, dataIndex : 'Category'},
                       {header : 'Room', sortable:true, width:140, dataIndex : 'Name'}
                    ],

                    store : resourceStore,
                    resourceStore : resourceStore,
                    eventStore : eventStore,


                    tbar : [
                        {
                            iconCls : 'icon-previous',
                            scale : 'medium',
                            handler : function() {
                                g.shiftPrevious();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text : 'Week',
                            toggleGroup : 'presets',
                            enableToggle : true,
                            pressed : false,
                            iconCls : 'icon-calendar',
                            handler : function() {
                                var newdate = new Date();
                                newdate.setDate(new Date().getDate()+6);
                                g.switchViewPreset('Scheduler', new Date(), newdate);
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text : '10 Days',
                            toggleGroup : 'presets',
                            enableToggle : true,
                            pressed : false,
                            iconCls : 'icon-calendar',
                            handler : function() {
                                var newdate = new Date();
                                newdate.setDate(new Date().getDate()+9);
                                g.switchViewPreset('Scheduler', new Date(), newdate);
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text : '2 Week',
                            toggleGroup : 'presets',
                            enableToggle : true,
                            pressed : false,
                            iconCls : 'icon-calendar',
                            handler : function() {
                                var newdate = new Date();
                                newdate.setDate(new Date().getDate()+13);
                                g.switchViewPreset('Scheduler', new Date(), newdate);
                            }
                        },
                        '->',
                        {
                            iconCls : 'icon-next',
                            scale : 'medium',
                            handler : function() {
                                g.shiftNext();
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    listeners : {
                        eventcontextmenu    : this.onEventContextMenu,
                        //For the Booking Confirmation
                        beforeeventadd : function(s,ev) {


                            if(Ext.Date.format(ev.getEndDate(), 'm/d/Y') < Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'm/d/Y') || Ext.Date.format(ev.getStartDate(), 'm/d/Y') < Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'm/d/Y'))
                            {
                                alert ('You Cant Book Room of Old Date');
                                return false;
                            }
                            else
                                {
                                    var endDate = ev.getEndDate();
                                    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()-1);
                                    var r=confirm("Would you like to Book Room. \n  Booking Date = " 
                                                  +Ext.Date.format(ev.getStartDate(), 'm/d/Y') + '  To  ' + Ext.Date.format(endDate, 'm/d/Y'));
                                    if (r==true)
                                        {
                                            submitForm('main.htm','weekCalander,roomId,roomName,startDateWeekCal,endDateWeekCal,hotelIdWeekCal','1,'+ev.getResourceId()+','+ev.getResourceId()+','+Ext.Date.format(ev.getStartDate(), 'm/d/Y')+','+Ext.Date.format(endDate, 'm/d/Y')+','+$('#hiddenHotelId').val());
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                }
                        },

                        eventDrop: function(view,records,isCopy,eOpts){

                                var mapObj = new Object();
                                dwrMainCommand.getBookingDataByBookingId(records[0].getId(),{
                                    async:false,
                                    callback : function(data) {
                                        if(data != null){
                                            mapObj.noOfGuest = data[0][31];
                                            mapObj.convectionId = data[0][35];
                                        }
                                    },
                                });

                                mapObj.hotelId = $('#hiddenHotelId').val();
                                mapObj.roomId = records[0].getResourceId();
                                mapObj.bookingId = records[0].getId();
                                mapObj.startDate = Ext.Date.format(records[0].getStartDate(), 'm/d/Y');
                                mapObj.endDate = Ext.Date.format(records[0].getEndDate(), 'm/d/Y');


                                dwrMainCommand.updateRoomPriceByRoom(mapObj,{
                                    async:false,
                                    callback : function(data) {
                                        if(data != null){
                                            alert('Booking Id : ' + records[0].getId() + '  New Price: ' + data.price +' local Tax:' + data.localTax + ' State Tax:' + data.stateTax);
                                        }
                                    },
                                });
                        },
                        beforeeventresize : function(s, r) {
                            return false;
                        },
                        eventresizeend: function(s, records,opt) {
                            return false;
                            /*records.data.EndDate
                            records.data.StartDate
                            records.data.ResourceId
                            records.data.Name
                            records.data.Id
                             */
                            /*var r=confirm("Change Booking Date from: " + Ext.Date.format( records.data.StartDate, 'm/d/Y') + " To :" + Ext.Date.format( records.data.EndDate, 'm/d/Y'));
                            if (r==true)
                            {
                            alert("ID=" + records.data.Id);

                            alert("ID=" + records.data.ResourceId);
                            alert("ID=" + records.data.Name);
                            alert("ID=" + records.data.StartDate);
                            alert("ID=" + records.data.EndDate);
                            return true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 //resourceStore.load();
                                 //eventStore.load();
                                return false;
                            }
                            */
                        }
                    }

                });

                resourceStore.load();
                eventStore.load();

                return g;
            }
        };
```

Is there any changes in existing code then plz suggest me. one more think if i removed "resourceStore.load" and "eventStore.load" than console errror will be removed but some functionality will not be worked in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
just put following code to initialize eventStore and resource store.  



var resourceStore = Ext.create('Sch.data.ResourceStore', {
                groupField : 'Category',
                sorters: ['Category','Name'],
                model : 'Resource',
                sucess:true,
                proxy: { 
                    type: 'ajax', 
                    url: '', 
                    reader: { 
                       root: 'data', 
                       type: 'json' 
                    } 
                }, 
                data : roomList,
         });



 eventStore = Ext.create('Sch.data.EventStore', {
            sucess:true,
             proxy: { 
                    type: 'ajax', 
                   url: '', 
                    reader: { 
                        root: 'data', 
                        type: 'json' 
                   } 
                }, 
              data : bookRoom,
            });
```